# hiding datapager in GridView when page number =1

Tags: c#, gridview, datapager

I'm using gridview , and a datapager in it , I couldn't find a way to hide the pager. I tried this code :

```
pager.Visible = (pager.PageSize < pager.TotalRowCount);
```

Is there any other way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code if you add it in the OnDataBound event

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     pager.Visible = (pager.PageSize < pager.TotalRowCount); 
}
```